# Issue in updating elements in multidimensional vector in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, vector

I am trying to update elements in 2D Vector(in fact I am creating a ((n*n) xn) matrix ) based on a condition which I will mention in the sample code.

Here is the sample code.

```
public class TestMatrix{
    private Vector<Vector<Integer>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();

    public void matrixUpdate(){
        int n = 9;
        Vector<Integer> tmpMatrix = new Vector<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) tmpMatrix.addElement(-1);  // initialize 
                                                      //tmpMatrix
        for(int j = 0; j < n*n; j++){
            marix.addElement(tmpMatrix);
        }  // initialize matrix
        for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
               int a = i/n; 
               int b = i%n;
               int c = j;
               System.out.print("r" + a + "r" + b + "r" + c + "\t");
               //condition for updating elements
               if(a == b){
                   matrix.get(i).set(j,-1);
                   continue;
               }
               if(b == c){
                   matrix.get(i).set(j,-1);
                   continue;
               }
               if(a == c) {
                   matrix.get(i).set(j,-1);
                   continue;
               }
               matrix.get(i).set(j,99);
            }
            System.out.println(matrix.get(i));
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < (n*n); i++){
            System.out.println(matrix.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestMatrix testMatrix = new TestMatrix();
        testMatrix.matrixUpdate();
    }
}
```

You can run the above code and check for yourselves. As per the output that I got it is not what I am expecting.

Any help is appreciable. Better implementation of the above logic is deeply appreciable.

Cheers.

Edit: Expected result (for n=8 a n*n size vector with each element as a n-size vector):

```
[
  [99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1],
  [99 99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1],
  [99 -1 99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1],
  [99 -1 -1 99 -1 -1 -1 -1],
  [99 -1 -1 -1 99 -1 -1 -1],
  [99 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -1 -1],
  [99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -1],
  [99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99],
  [99 99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1],
  [-1 99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1],
   ... total 64 lines ...
]
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: Edited the code now. check it @Aaron

Comment: I expect the matrix to get updated. @StephaneM

Comment: Everything is already -1... why do you keep setting things again to -1?

Comment: This is my guess of what you are trying to do: Lets take n is 8. There there is a Vector[8*8=64] long, each item in the list is a Vector[8]. So there are 0-63 vectors.. each of length 8. Here you are changing only couple of places to 99.. rest of the places are -1.

Comment: matrix[0] = [99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1], matrix[1] = [99 99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1], matrix[2] = [99 -1 99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1] etc.

Comment: So, what do you want to change in this

Comment: So, once I'm done with assignment and if I want to retrieve any of the vector within matrix 2d vector I have to get the updated vector. Let's say if I want to print matrix.get(2) I have to get this  [99,-1,99,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], but I'm getting this [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1] . @Teddy

Comment: Keep only one -1 for initializing tmpMatrix. Probably the other -1's are overwriting the 99s. Just keep the 'continue;' and remove the -1s inside the double for loop.

Comment: Actually, if it matches, you should be setting 99 right?

Comment: Where am I going wrong if I am not getting the expected result? Coz, I have to use this vector in another method with updated values in it.

Comment: a==b condition also looks suspicious. It writes the whole line.

Comment: N,o actually I have done the same thing what you mentioned just now. If just keep continue without setting it to -1 then the elements are getting overwritten by 99. So that's why I came up with this implementation. @Teddy